# Create a new table from two existing table

Tags: sql-server-2008

> Hello,
>
> I need your help. I am trying to create a new table using two existing table (TABLE1 and TABLE2). I have no
>           idea what SQL Server technique I can use to resolve this issue.

```
SELECT A AS A1, B AS B1, C AS C1 FROM TABLE1
Result:
        A1  B1  C1
        3   4   1
        1   2   0

SELECT E2 AS A1, F2 AS B1, G2 AS C1 FROM TABLE2
Result:
        A1  B1  C1
        4   7   1
        2   8   6
```

> Let’s name the new table 'My_Table' which includes all data from TABLE1 and TABLE2.

```
SELECT * FROM My_Table
Result:
        A1  B1  C1
        3   4   1
        1   2   0
        4   7   1
        2   8   6
```

> I want to save this table in my database and use it in the future.
>
> Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the [INTO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) clause and a [UNION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) of both selects.

```
SELECT A AS A1, B AS B1, C AS C1 
INTO My_Table
FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT E2 AS A1, F2 AS B1, G2 AS C1 
FROM TABLE2
```

Note, that a UNION will also remove duplicate records. If that is not expected, then check out UNION ALL.